# error while removing Anydesk

Tags: 22.04, anydesk

Could you please let me know what it the correct method to remove Anydesk?

I am receiving this error, while I am trying below command:

```
sudo apt-get remove anydesk
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-tools-5.15.0-56 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: You had a package problem with your prior command, which needs to be fixed before you can run other commands; that error message should have reminded you to fix the prior command failures.  It provided a first suggestion; ie. `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, so did you try it?

Comment: I didn't even know that Anydesk was in a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=========================

#additional#

```
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

=========================

Try this below comments

```
sudo apt autoremove anydesk --purge -y
```

To remove Repositories;

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk.list
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/anydesk.gpg
```

Once the package is broken we need to use this command to fix it. `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: after you instruction I could remove it with this command:$ flatpak uninstall flathub com.anydesk.Anydesk. thank you